# How do I give two range sliders a different track-color?

Tags: html, css, input, slider, range

Could someone explain to me how I can make these two slider-tracks have a different color?

Very much appreciated, as i'm tearing my hairs out over something so seemingly "simple" (apologies if im wrong)

```css
input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
'
'
'
<input type="range">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign different classes to the input elements and give respective background colors. Please refer the snippet below.

```css
input[type=range].bgRed::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{
  background-color:red;
}
input[type=range].bgBlue::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="range" class="bgRed">
'
'
'
<input type="range" class="bgBlue">
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

Comment: I know we're not supposed to say thank you, but I'm a bit of a rebel and a thug so; thank you! =)

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS

```
input[type=range]:nth-child(1)::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{
  background-color:red;
}
input[type=range]:nth-child(2)::-webkit-slider-runnable-track{
  background-color:green;
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]